# Next js trying to fetch data then pass it to a client components but it's not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

im fetching data asynchronously then passing it to a client component as props
then sitting the state of the client component and displaying it but it's not working
the props are passing fine but the state is not getting set for some reason

server component :

```
export default async function Blog({ params }) {
  const id = params.id;
  const blog = await GetBlog(id);
  return (
    <>
      <Edit
        title="test"
        date={blog[0].date_c}
        disc={blog[0].disc}
        content={blog[0].content}
      />
    </>
  );
```

client component :

```
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Edit({ _title, _disc, _content, _date }) {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(_title);
  const [disc, setDisc] = useState(_disc);
  const [content, setContent] = useState(_content);
  const [date, setDate] = useState(_date);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="blog-read">
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <small>{date}</small>
        <p>
          <b>{disc}</b>
        </p>
        <p>{content}</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

It's supposed to show the components with the data busting from the props
I tried passing a normal string it didn't work also
the data is being fetched correctly asynchronously
I think the problem might be that the component is being rendered before the data is being fetched but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The prop's name is different they should be the same.**

Wrong : Edit({ **_title, _disc, _content, _date** })

Correct : Edit({ **title, disc, content, date** })

Let me know if it still does not work.